# error:ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement QtCore (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for QtCore

Tags: pip, qtcore

When I run `pip install QtCore` it returns:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement QtCore (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for QtCore
```

Answer (score 0):

[QtCore does not exist on Pypi](https://pypi.org/project/QtCore/). What you probably want is PyQt5:

```bash
pip install PyQt5
```

and then access QtCore like this:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
```

See the [PyQt5 documentation](https://docs.huihoo.com/pyqt/PyQt5/QtCore.html).